# Safety for different years

Tags: ford, safety

I am considering buying the Ford S-Max, second-hand. I went to [euroncap](http://www.euroncap.com/en) to see safety ratings, but they rate only 2 years: the 2015 model and the 2006 model.

I need to make a choice between a few different years: 2006, 2008, 2010 and 2013.
Will the safety of the car be the same for all these years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2006 through 2015 use the same chassis and the same systems, therefore they have essentially the same safety.  All of them have ABS, EBD (brake-force distribution), and ESP (stability control).  All have airbags and pretensioner seatbelts.

In late 2015 a new model was introduced which in some markets is a 2015, in others is a MY2016.  This model is all new and would have different safety ratings.